# Secure Gateway Client for Os400

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-midrange, secure-gateway

Do we have Bluemix Secure gateway client that can be used to connect to DB2 database on OS 400?  The bluemix documentation does not mention about client for for OS400 @ https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/secure_gateway.html#client

I had gone through [how to connect a bluemix app to on-premise db/as400?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660064/how-to-connect-a-bluemix-app-to-on-premise-db-as400) , which mentions about Secure gateway client for OS 400. Wanted to understand how to configure the same?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an OS/400 Secure Gateway client to connect to an AS/400 system. It's sufficient to install the client on any machine on the same network as your AS/400 server and configure the client to allow access to the database IP address and port.

Comment: Thank you. WIll try the same

Comment: hi mustaccio, Do we need to configure any special settings in the machine where we install Secure gateway client to connect to AS/400?  Can you please help me with any specific settings. Does it require and DB2 client software to be installed ?

Comment: No, you don't need the DB2 client on the gateway, as you wouldn't need it on a VPN server. Follow the setup instructions on Bluemix and post another question if you have any particular issue.

Comment: Have raised question with issue I am facing @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268703/bluemix-secure-gateway-as-400-db2-connection-refused-issue